# Finding the nth non square free number

Tags: number-theory

We all know what [squarefree](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Squarefree.html) numbers are. I was more interested in checking an efficient way to find nth non square free number.

Comment: Are you looking for a mathematical formula or just a piece of code that can do it efficiently?

Comment: Start with a good guess (obtained from the asymptotic density of squarefree numbers), count the number of squarefree numbers not exceeding the guess, and find the right number by sieving a small enough range above/below the initial guess. If the initial guess was too wide off, it can be good to make another guess before sieving.

Comment: Expanding Daniel Fischer's comment, the density of non-squarefree numbers is $1-\frac{6}{\pi^2}$, hence the initial guess can be taken as $$\frac{N}{1-\frac{6}{\pi^2}}\approx\frac{23}{9}\,N.$$

Comment: This is a problem statement from an ongoing programming contest. This is an unhealthy practice. Request the community to refrain from answering it as it is done in an unethical fashion. Ref to question: https://www.codechef.com/JAN18/problems/SQRGOOD Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $S(n)$ be the count of squarefree numbers less than or equal to $n$. Note that each integer $n$ has a unique "squarefree decomposition" $n = a^2b$ where $b$ is squarefree.

One approach is to start with $n$ and then remove the counts we don't want, i.e. anything with $a>1$. Using inclusion-exclusion, this suggests a recursion:

$$S(n) = n - \sum_{a=2}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor} S\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{a^2}\right\rfloor\right)$$

This isn't the most efficient approach as-stated, but it's a good starting point for additional insights and optimizations. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for the above help, this is what I am doing right now, but its not fast enough when it comes to 10^14.

Comment: At the very least, memoize the values of $S$ so that you're not recomputing intermediate values. Past that, a hint: Output the values of $\left\lfloor n/a^2 \right\rfloor$ for some reasonably large $n$ (say $10^6$). Notice anything interesting?

Answer (score -2):

The $n$-th non square integer is given by the formula $n + [ \sqrt{n} + 0.5],$ where $[•]$ denotes floor function. E.g. $n=1$ yields $2$, $n=2$ yields $3$, $n=3$ yields $5$,...and so on. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Can you now find a similar algebraic formula for the n-th non cube integer?

Comment: A number is squarefree if no square other than $1$ divides it, which is quite different from what you've written. So, no, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Non-square is not the same thing as squarefree.