# $N$-th number divisible by a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

What is the fastest algorithm to determine the $n$-th number divisible by a perfect square?
For example,

$n=1$, answer=$4$;

$n=2$, answer=$8$;

$n=3$, answer=$9$;

$n=4$, answer=$12$

Comment: You mean a perfect square $\ge 4$, right?

Comment: This is https://oeis.org/A013929, where no simple calculation is given.  An approximate answer is $a_n \approx \frac n{1-\frac 6{\pi ^2}}$

Comment: I am starting to believe this comes from an active contest, since it has been asked just a few hours ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599847/finding-the-nth-non-square-free-number#comment5368327_2599847

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I've got the same suspicion, that's why I didn't answer it.

Comment: Yes,indeed it is from a contest. But I just wanted to know the approach of the solution. Actually, the size of n is of the order 10^18 and the time limit is 2 secs, so the solution has to be better than O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Sort in ascending order the elements of the set $$\bigcup_{k=2}^{\sqrt n}\left\{k^2l~\bigm|~1\le l\le\left\lfloor\frac n{k^2}\right\rfloor+1\right\}$$ and take the $n^{th}$ element.

But this might not be the most efficient algorithm.

Comment: No, certainly not, especially for large $n$ (it would eat up lots of RAM, too), it's a $O(n)$ algorithm, while $O(n^{1/3}\log^C n)$ seems to be practical, and further optimizations possible.

Comment: Yes, I want a more efficient algorithm.